# Why even flag as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Why do we flag questions as duplicates? After so long the accepted answers may become out of date. Is there a set duration after which duplicates are allowed?

Comment: How ironic this was marked duplicate. I tried searching to see if this had already been asked and could not find it, now I'm down voted and (new user) further discouraged from the project. Finally, the accepted answer of the "duplicate" question did not answer my question about changing accepted answers. This Q&A point system is starting to fail, the quick close and down vote so that I lose reputation is a terribly discouraging to new participants. Just make it a wiki already!

Comment: How much reputation did you lose?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it doesn't go down since I got my points from the main site and not on meta. I think you shouldn't be able to downvote duplicates. It's not a bad a question, it's just already been answered.

Comment: You do not lose reputation on meta.so. Also, please consider reading that duplicate thoroughly, as it talks about everything in your question, since your question does not in fact ask about changing accepted answers. Finally, votes are up to each individual.

Comment: Sure, no problem about this being marked as duplicate, I'll refer to the other question. As for the points I'm saying you shouldn't be able to downvote duplicates on StackOverflow. A duplicate is not a bad question, just a duplicate. The downvotes discourage new users (I'm not saying I'm one). I basically am questioning the point system altogether. Sorry the comments here are probably not the right venue to discuss this

Answer (score 6):

We flag questions as duplicates so that all the correct answers to a given problem are gathered in one place, and can be updated as needed in one place.

By keeping the duplicate and marking it as such, we give the users who come to SO through Google the ability to find the right answer even if the question is worded differently than the original question.

Comment: This is sensible, but older answers will become irrelevant. We then have to somehow change the accepted answer, and more or less remove the old ones or make it clear that they are no longer accurate. If you keep following this system, you're basically running a wiki. However most users are going to look the highest upvoted answer, which could be years old, this is a serious flaw in the point system.